# How to customize authentication backend in django social auth?

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I am trying to customize social_auth.backends.contrib.vk.VKOAuth2Backend
but when I enable my custom backend get this error

> WrongBackend at /login/vk-oauth/
>
> Incorrect authentication service "vk-oauth"

authentication_backends from settings

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.vk.VKOAuth2Backend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2Backend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.odnoklassniki.OdnoklassnikiBackend',
    # '_auth.backends.CustomVKOAuth2Backend',
    'profiles.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Problem occurs if I uncomment my CustomVKOAuth2Backend, but with  VKOAuth2Backend everything works like expected.

```
from social_auth.backends.contrib.vk import VKOAuth2Backend

class CustomVKOAuth2Backend(VKOAuth2Backend):
    """Custom VKOAuth2 authentication backend"""

    def get_user_details(self, response):
        """Return user details from VK account"""
        lname = response.get('last_name', '')
        fname = response.get('first_name', '')
        name = fname + lname
        email = response.get('email', '')

        return {
            'username': response.get('screen_name'),
            'email': email,
            'first_name': fname,
            'last_name': lname,
            'name': name
        }
```

they are almost indentical so I can not understand where is the problem
This is backend that works

```
class VKOAuth2Backend(OAuthBackend):
    """VKOAuth2 authentication backend"""
    name = 'vk-oauth'

    EXTRA_DATA = [
        ('id', 'id'),
        ('expires', 'expires')
    ]

    def get_user_id(self, details, response):
        """OAuth providers return an unique user id in response"""
        return response['user_id']

    def get_user_details(self, response):
        """Return user details from VK account"""
        return {
            'username': response.get('screen_name'),
            'email': '',
            'first_name': response.get('first_name'),
            'last_name': response.get('last_name')
        }
```

Comment: Do you have ``SOCIAL_AUTH_VK_OAUTH2_KEY = ''`` and ``SOCIAL_AUTH_VK_OAUTH2_SECRET = ''`` variables in your ``settings.py``?

Comment: Yes, I have. And default backend is working with the same settings (VKOAuth2Backend ). Problem only occurs only if I switch in settings to my custom backend

Comment: Where was that class added ( social_auth.backends.contrib.vk.VKOAuth2Backend) . Did you have to find the library, social_auth and add it?